# Lightweight GitLab alternative for small company

Tags: free-software, gitlab

I'm looking for GitLab replacement, which does not require 4GB RAM and is easier to move/upgrade/migrate, does not have dependency hell and creates less than 50 processes on server.

There are 3, sometimes 4 programmers in my company, we don't need that many features.

We need just:

- add/remove repository
- add/edit/remove user
- add/remove user SSH key
- add/edit/remove group (of users)
- allow user or group to read/write repository

does such a thing exist or should we just use linux console?

Comment: You’ve mentioned nothing about issues and pull requests. If all you want is git hosting with permissions there is a super light weight option: https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html

Comment: Looks awesome. It does not even require root access to setup (if git and perl are installed). There is a lot of useful information about alternatives on this page. How about putting this as an answer?

Comment: It's a working, but invalid "answer". It doesn't solve the problem, just points to an external page. The link solves the problem, but the pointer to it doesn't.